# What does the "RAILS_GEM_VERSION" setting do exactly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, configuration

What is the purpose of the `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` setting in `config/environment.rb`? Is it supposed to stop your app from running under an unexpected version of Rails?

I just keep Rails updated to the latest release on my laptop and in production. Since I do that, can I comment out `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` or should I set it for some reason?

Comment: What about Rails 3 in combination with Bundler: we already know the version to load because the Gemfile decides that - does that mean  `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` is deprecated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can have more than one version of Rails installed on your system (you can check with gem list rails), your application needs to know which version it is supposed to use. It won't be very clever just to "keep Rails updated to the latest release" and let the application use the newest version, since since new version of Rails could very easily break it (every new release means some changes to the API). This constant is irrelevant, however, if you "freeze" the version of Rails your app is build for, in the vendor folder. Btw. freezing Rails is a good practice, since your app is then more independent on the environment.

Comment: You could also (now that bundler is so common) run `bundle exec` before the command you need to run.